# How can I create a new list as a result of combing two other lists?

Tags: c#, list

I trying to create a third list which is the result of combining two other lists, but I don't know how.

I've also been working on combining the first element in the first list (names) to the first element in the second list (states) and make them as the first element in the third list (employees).

For example, I would like the first element in the employee list to be as "Michael lives in Oregon".

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me with this. Thank you.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
   static void Main() 
   {
        // Initializing and Declaring the Lists
        List<string> names = new List<string>();
        List<string> states = new List<string>();
        List<string> employees = new List<string>();
    
        // names
        names.Add("Michael");    
        names.Add("Anna");    
        names.Add("Connor");    
        names.Add("Jane");    
        names.Add("Brian");   
    
        // states 
        states.Add("Oregon");
        states.Add("Florida");
        states.Add("New York");
        states.Add("California");
        states.Add("Kentucky");
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you want a new list or can one list be changed?

Comment: You'd maybe have to be a little more precise in what you mean by "combine".

Comment: @Fildor, *"Michael lives in Oregon"* = matching by same index.

Comment: Greetings Zak. 
Please read the guidelines for posting questions. Or you will experience negative points on your questions. 

You should provide enough code to reproduce an error, and an expected result of your code as a minimum when posting a question, this will help the coders that are donating their time, to answer the question you intend to ask, not the question they think you are asking.

Comment: @Sinatr At least to me it's not that clear if the question is just about exactly this case.

Comment: To me, it seems you could create a class to hold all the properties and then create a new list of this new class... From what I can see from your post, you don't need all those list to be honest unless there's something else you've excluded from your post.

Comment: Do the two lists always match in size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both Lists have the same length you can loop through one of them and then add both `names[i]` and `states[i]` into the new list.

**Solution without using Linq:**

```cs
if (names.Count == states.Count) {
    for (int i = 0; i < names.Count; ++i) {
        employees.Add(names[i] + " lives in " + states[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

[LINQ Zip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip) to the rescue:

```
var result = names
    .Zip(states, (name, state) => $"{name} lives in {state}")
    .ToList();
```

Comment: OP: For your reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netcore-3.1

Answer (score 2):

You could pull from names by name and index, then use the index to pull the correct value from states.

Then, use string.Format() with arguments to replace the {0} and {1} with name and states[index].

This can be done with linq like so:

```cs
List<string> employees = names
  .Select((name, index) => string.Format("{0} lives in {1}", name, states[index]))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Mind that you'd have to check that `states[index]` actually exists. i.e. `index` is in bounds of `states`.

Comment: @Fildor yeah I agree. I'm not really sure how this program would work in the real world for that exact reason - assumed it was more of a learning exercise